# PostgreSQL 9.3 How to set start-type to manual on Ubuntu?

Tags: startup, postgresql-9.3

my psql9.3 server is starting every time I turn on my computer. I've heard that it can make your computer slower so I'd like to start postgresql service on demand only.

According to [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-pg-ctl.html) website it's quite simple to do on Windows but I can't see such option for Linux.
I have also read [here](http://etutorials.org/SQL/Postgresql/Part+III+PostgreSQL+Administration/Chapter+19.+PostgreSQL+Administration/Arranging+for+PostgreSQL+Startup+and+Shutdown/) that if you want to set your start-type to auto on Linux you can

> "Copy the file start-scripts/linux from PostgreSQL's contrib directory
>   to /etc/rc.d/init.d/postgresql and then Execute the command /sbin/chkconfig".

So is it good idea to remove that file to switch on manual type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if PostgreSQL is idle it takes less CPU time than your mouse does. It may take some ram, but unless you are trying to run your computer without any GUI (shell prompt only) and have less than 1 GB this will be negligible.

If you feel you have to manually start PostgreSQL, you can always do the procedure you have listed in your question. Do a backup first and be prepared to reinstall PostgreSQL should everything go wrong.

Comment: You are rigth - wastage of RAM is really negligible.